# How to change background with a new image using JavaScript when each time the web page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, background-image

I have a web page with background image attached on body element I want to change background with a new image whenever the window is loaded so I wrote the following code but it is not working, I can't figure out as what I am missing.

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){  
var bgdynamic = document.getElementById("bgdynamic");  
var imgarray = new Array("bgs/bg_01.jpg", "bgs/bg_02.jpg", "bgs/bg_03.jpg", "bgs/bg_04.jpg", "bgs/bg_05.jpg", "bgs/bg_06.jpg", "bgs/bg_07.jpg");  
var spot = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarry.length);  
bgdynamic.style.backgroundImage="url("+imgarray[spot]+")";
};
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url(bgs/bg_01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
```

}

HTML:

```
<body id="bgdynamic">
Content goes...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed **a** in

```
var spot = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarry.length);
```

should be :

```
var spot = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarray.length);`
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bu84g/)

Comment: Many thanks, I have just figured out was a little spell mistake but it ruined lots of my time :)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have a problem with Math.random(), I think that this should fix it:

```
var spot = (Math.Random() * imgarray.length) * 10
```

Comment: The problem was a simple typing mistake `imgarry` instead of `imgarray`. PS. I don't like using up points for down-votes, so feel free to delete your incorrect answer :)